# How to update table on session timeout and redirect to home page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Update table on session timeout**

```
$idletime = 200; // After this time the user gets logged out

if (time() - $_SESSION['timestamp'] >= $idletime){
    // Update this Query When Time Is over
    $qry = "UPDATE users SET status = ' ' WHERE seats = '".$_SESSION['seats']."' and id='".$ID."'";
    mysqli_query($con, $qry);
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:index.php");
} else {
    // First Time Run This Query
    // This query run  perfectly
    $qry = "UPDATE users SET status = 'HOLD' WHERE seats = '".$_SESSION['seats']."' and id='".$ID."'";
    mysqli_query($con, $qry);
    $_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();
}
```

How to update table on session timeout and redirect to home page?

Comment: You will have to use javascript or jquery to accomplish this. After idletime call the file with this update query.

Comment: i used "header(Location)" but its not working can you tell me please how can be its possible with javascript?

Comment: These might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700008/show-countdown-time-form-jquery-session-timeout  and http://www.itworld.com/article/2832447/development/how-to-create-a-session-timeout-warning-for-your-web-application-using-jquery.html