# Session timeout counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a session timeout counter, so that after 15 minutes of inactivity the customer basket is deleted, the code I have so far half works but I cannot work out how to create the counter to keep track of the time. I have set the time to a low number to test

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sessionTimeoutWarning =1;
    var sessionTimeout = 3;
    var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;

    var timeOnPageLoad = new Date();
    setTimeout(sessionWarning(), sTimeout);

    function sessionWarning() {
        var minutesForExpiry = (parseInt(sessionTimeout) - parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning));
        var message = "Your session will expire in another " + minutesForExpiry + " mins! Please continue browsing before your basket is deleted.";
        alert(message);
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var timeForExpiry = timeOnPageLoad.setMinutes(timeOnPageLoad.getMinutes() + parseInt(sessionTimeout));
        if (Date.parse(currentTime) > timeForExpiry) {
            alert("Session expired. Items in the basket will be deleted.");
            window.location = "/";
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: this might help in your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700008/show-countdown-time-form-jquery-session-timeout

Comment: What is supposed to happen if I have two tabs open, and I keep the session alive in one of them? The other would appear to be expired, when in reality my session is still very much alive. If you need to manage sessions to this tight level, I'd suggest using WebSockets. That way it's dealt with by the server and all clients will be kept in sync.

Comment: You need to do an ajax call to the server. And have your logic server side

Comment: @SeanT AJAX is just a one-time state check though.

Comment: You are passing the return value of `sessionWarning` to setTimeout, not the function itself. You have to pass it like `setTimeout(sessionWarning, sTimeout);`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't understand what you're point is sorry - I'm just pointing out that you need to poll the server. In the past I've kept a guid on each tab to identify if two open, and send these in requests but that's another matter I guess